# Flex item justify content not working properly with margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a 2 items inside a div.

```css
#picBox {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #8D918D;
  background-image: url('images/IMG_1744.JPG');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  display: flex;
}

#overlay {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 80%;
}

#olText {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1,
p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="picBox">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div id="olText">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the 2 items (h1 and p) alligned vertically in the middle of #olText. Also want the items to be 10 px from the left side of the div, at least 10 px from the top (when needed, becouse lot of text), and 10 px from eachother.

Now it seams, since I am using margins, the flex justify-content is not working. What is the solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with your code. `h1` and `p` are vertically aligned in the center. The reason that it doesn't seem so is because the height of `#olText` is the same as the total height of `h1 + margin-top` and `p`. You may need to adjust the height of `#olText` using `min-height`

If you need to align them horizontally in the center, use  `align-items:center;`.

```css
#olText {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  min-height: 200px;
}

h1,
p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="olText">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set flex container as well as html and body to full height.

```css
#olText {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


h1, p {
    margin-left: 10px; 
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
} 

p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="olText">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <p>Description</p>
</div>
```